# Running md files in Julia REPL in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, markdown

I have a `MD` file which I want to debug and make sure it works properly. I like to run its code cells one by one in Julia REPL. How can I do that in VS Code?

Comment: Not sure about VSCode, but you can run Julia code blocks from Markdown files in RStudio

Answer (score 2):

You should first install the [Julia for VSCode extension](https://www.julia-vscode.org) and follow its setup instructions. Then you just start cells with the magic comment `##`, and then use the command "execute code cell in REPL" or its keyboard shortcut. Example file:

```
##
println("first")

##
println("second")
```